# Why does on authenticate(..) the returned Authentication object still need to contain the credentials?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm just on some specifications for a coming project and stumbled over detail of the AuthenticationProvider interface of Spring Security.

For the method `Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)` 
the returned object is again a `Authentication` object. According the java doc from Spring it says for the return value:

> Returns:
>       a fully authenticated object including credentials. May return null if the AuthenticationProvider is unable to support authentication of the passed Authentication object. In such a case, the next AuthenticationProvider that supports the presented Authentication class will be tried.

Why should the object still contain the credentials after I successfully authenticated? This doesn't make sense to me. After an authentication, I want to purge all information about the credential immediately,or why shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security removes the sensitive credentials information, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-erasing-credentials):

> **10.1.1 Erasing Credentials on Successful Authentication**
>
> By default (from Spring Security 3.1 onwards) the `ProviderManager` will attempt to clear any sensitive credentials information from the Authentication object which is returned by a successful authentication request. This prevents information like passwords being retained longer than necessary.
>
> This may cause issues when you are using a cache of user objects, for example, to improve performance in a stateless application. If the `Authentication` contains a reference to an object in the cache (such as a `UserDetails` instance) and this has its credentials removed, then it will no longer be possible to authenticate against the cached value. You need to take this into account if you are using a cache. An obvious solution is to make a copy of the object first, either in the cache implementation or in the `AuthenticationProvider` which creates the returned `Authentication` object. Alternatively, you can disable the `eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication` property on `ProviderManager`. See the Javadoc for more information.

Comment: Thanks,that's what I would have expected. So the Java doc is a bit confusing as it says explicitly `a fully authenticated object including credentials.`.